# Explain why $\prod_\limits{n=N}^{M}\{1-P(A_n)\}\leqslant\prod_\limits{n=N}^{M}e^{-P(A_n)}$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$, and let $A =\limsup A_n$ Suppose moreover that the events $A_n$ are independent.Then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)=\infty$$

implies that  $P(A)=1$.

I got lost on the following step of the proof:

$$\prod_{n=N}^M\{1-P(A_n)\}\leqslant\prod_{n=N}^M e^{-P(A_n)}$$

Where does the exponential come from?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a very basic inequality: for any real number $x$, we have $1-x\leq e^{-x}$. One way to explain why it holds is because $e^{-x}$ is convex and the line $1-x$ is a supporting line for it at $x=0$

Answer (score 4):

This is just the inequality $1-x\le e^{-x}$ valid for $0\le x\le1$.
It's easily proved by calculus.

Why introduce exponentials? They are easier to multiply: $\prod e^{-p_n}=\exp\left(-\sum p_n\right)$ etc.

Comment: Actually the inequality $1-x \le e^{-x}$ is valid if $x$ is any real number at all; it doesn't have to be between $0$ and $1.$ (But only the case $0\le x\le 1$ is applied in this problem.) $\qquad$